# placeholder for any code

Tags: java, reflection

I need to define a object at runtime like below.

```
 Filter rowFilter = new RowFilter(CompareFilter.CompareOp.EQUAL,
 new RegexStringComparator(".*-.5"));
```

I am reading one String which is having code like below

```
String _filterString = "RowFilter(CompareFilter.CompareOp.EQUAL,
     new RegexStringComparator(\".*-.5\"))";
```

Now I need to define a filter object by using the above String.

I know, this type of problems we can achieve by using Reflections.But I am looking for alternatives. Is there any simple way to solve problems like this?

Comment: If `_filterString` comes from user input, don't do that. If it comes from database, you should serialize java object directly (xstream?).

Comment: thanks for reply. There are lot of filters are available and the parameters also varies from filter to filter. It will be so easy to me if i read as a single string from input. I am implementing by using reflections and as well i am also looking for alternatives. Here my question is about possibility of placeholder in java. Is there any simple way?

Answer (score 2):

The Java Scripting API allows embedding of miscellaneous languages like JavaScript and have bindings to Java variables and methods. In your case the language BeanShell (Java subset) can be used.

Answer (score 1):

[Java Compiler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) can be used for compiling at Runtime, but it requires a full source (Compilation Unit). I don't think a single expression can be compiled. Maybe, you can work out from here to get your objects from the classes compiled at runtime.